# Proguard and com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.BasePendingResult$ReleasableResultGuardian

Tags: android, google-play-services, proguard

`play-services-base-16.0.1.aar` ([mvnrepository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.android.gms/play-services-base/16.0.1)) has `proguard.txt` with following content:

```
# b/35135904 Ensure that proguard will not strip the mResultGuardian.
-keepclassmembers class com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.BasePendingResult {
  com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.BasePendingResult$ReleasableResultGuardian mResultGuardian;
}
```

But you can see in `classes.jar` that type of `mResultGuardian` is already obfuscated to `BasePendingResult.zaa`. I guess that is why I get

```
Note: the configuration refers to the unknown class 'com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.BasePendingResult$ReleasableResultGuardian'
```

How that's supposed to work? I'm new to Proguard and only have very basic understanding of what is going on so please make your answers simple :)

Project details:

```
gradlew version: 5.4
build plugin: com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0
```

Unfortunatelly I can't update gradle build plugin to `3.3.*` or `3.4.*` right now because some of the scripts are incompatible and would require significant refactoring.

`app/proguard.txt` (from recommendations I've seen):

```
-keep class com.google.android.gms.analytics.** { *; }
-keep class com.google.android.gms.gcm.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.google.android.gms.**
```

But that doesn't help.

***UPD***

I end up upgrading to `com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.1` (some api changes had to be adapted) which fixed the issue but I still don't get how that's supposed to work with rules like that.

Answer (score 0):

“If the proguard set up in your project it does some jobs for us in the built process : Minification, obfuscation, repackaging and optimisation. Enabling it is straightforward if you’re using gradle, just set minifyEnabled to true for your release buildType in build.gradle and pass the default set of android optimisation rules.

This will help to shrink, speed up and protect your app. However it mainly works by removing code that is never called and renaming what’s left. This is all well and good until you encounter reflection.
Reflection lets you write code that can look up and execute other code based on its name (among other things)”

“You can also use ProGuard if you or any of the libraries in your app use reflection,  here you  specify rules as to which classes, methods and other parts of your app ProGuard should leave alone. You can list all these rules in a file and pass them to ProGuard via the proguardFiles method back in your build.gradle. The general convention is for this file to be called proguard-rules.pro”

These [doc1](https://medium.com/@jonfinerty/beginner-to-proguard-b3327ff3a831), [doc2](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/practical-proguard-rules-examples-5640a3907dc9) provide you more information on how to work with rules